# Not able to start Kibana in local ubuntu : Service Unavailable :: {"path":"/_cluster/settings"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed elastic 6.6 on Ubuntu and it is running fine on port 9200.

I also created a new data using my json file.

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/product/default/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary "@test-data.json"

But when I start kibana it throws an error.

> error  [06:27:47.587] [warning][process] Service Unavailable ::
>   {"path":"/_cluster/settings","query":{"include_defaults":true},"statusCode":503,"response":"
>
> ## 503
>   Service Unavailable
>
> \nNo server is available to handle this
>   request.\n\n\n"}
>       at respond (/home/svaibhav/Downloads/kibana-6.6.0-linux-x86_64/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:308:15)
>       at checkRespForFailure (/home/svaibhav/Downloads/kibana-6.6.0-linux-x86_64/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:267:7)
>       at HttpConnector. (/home/svaibhav/Downloads/kibana-6.6.0-linux-x86_64/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:165:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/home/svaibhav/Downloads/kibana-6.6.0-linux-x86_64/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4935:19)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)   log   [06:27:48.009] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive
>   connection: http://localhost:9200/   log   [06:27:48.009]
>   [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connections

EDIT:
IT IS RESOLVED NOW. There were two services running on 9200 port.
one on TCP other on tcpV6. Elastic was up on tcpv6, but kibana was looking on tcp 9200 port.
I changed the port on elastic and it worked.

Comment: Can you share your Kibana configuration?

Comment: Can you please also run the following command on the Kibana host machine and share the result? 
curl -i http://localhost:9200

Comment: @Val Kibana has default configuration. No changes done.

Comment: @kahveci HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 493
{
  "name" : "Taz2uuW",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "uJ1s6G3GSzmzCCsYQ7F34Q",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.6.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "a9861f4",
    "build_date" : "2019-01-24T11:27:09.439740Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}